# Inject new string into Fragment/ViewModel from MainActivity class

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Working with the android studio Bottom Navigation activity template, want my `HomeFragment` / `HomeViewModel` page text to change each time the Home is accessed from the bottom navigation. When I click it the first time the text it displays should be different from the text displayed the 2nd time.

I'm able to create a variable that holds the text output, and I've created a function that should be able to update that variable but I'm unable to call it up within the `MainActivity` class. Any ideas?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))


        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

**HomeFragment**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    var chosenOutput:String = "primary output";

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //using update here crashes the app
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = chosenOutput; //changing 'chosenOutput' to 'it' means that text update must take place within HomeViewModel instead of fragment.
        })
       
        return root
    }
    fun update(result: String)
    {
        chosenOutput = result; 
    }
}
```

**HomeViewModel**

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var temp:String = "demo"
    //constructor()
    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = temp;
    }
    fun update(result: String) //function may be obsolete if text change can be done in fragment.
    {
        temp = result; 
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text

}
```

What is the correct way to inject a string into either the `Fragment` or the `ViewModel` from the `MainActivity` class I've given?

Comment: use sharedviewmodel sceoped to activity and use livedata setting values and observing the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your approach and store your `chosenOutput` variable in the `MainActivity`
and update it everytime you select the `HomeFragment`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() 
{
    var chosenOutput = "primary output"
    ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications))

        navView.apply {
            setupWithNavController(navController)

            setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
                when (menuItem.itemId) {
                    R.id.navigation_home -> {
                        chosenOutput = "new value" // <-- Update chosen output here
                        // Add this method to call the `onResume` method in the fragment
                        showFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance())
                    }
                    else { }
                }

                true
        }
    }

    private fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the updated string in your `Fragment` with this code.
Note that I added the `companion object` to avoid the creation of multiple instances of the `Fragment`.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() 
{
    companion object
    {
        fun newInstance() : HomeFragment
        {
            return HomeFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        val newChosenOutput = (activity as MainActivity).chosenOutput
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, still outputs "primary output". After that didn't work I tried changing `val newChosenOutput = (activity as MainActivity).chosenOutput` into `chosenOutput = (activity as MainActivity).chosenOutput` but that didn't work either, seems it doesn't reach onResume()?

Comment: I edited the answer and added the code to programmatically set the current fragment when the navigation item is selected. Now, it should reach the `onResume` method.

Comment: @luce_999 there doesn't appear to be a reference for `MenuFragment`, I'm unable to `return` it or create `newInstance` as an instance of it.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled it, I was referring to `HomeFragment`